# Rows with at least one matched object through a 'has_many through' relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My Models are set up as follows:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :activity
    has_many :codes, -> { order("codes.name") }, through: :activity

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :activity_code_links
    has_many :codes, through: :activity_code_links
    has_many :records

class ActivityCodeLink < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :activity
    belongs_to :code

class Code < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :activity_code_links
    has_many :activities, through: :activity_code_links
    has_many :records, through: :activities
```

In a controller, i have an ActiveRecord Relation of records, @records.
I would like my resulting @records to only contain Records that have a specific Code.

Currently, i am using the below solution; however it is not efficient and also returns an Array, not an ActiveRecord Relation:

```
  @records = @records.reject { |record| (record.codes & [code]).empty? }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@records.joins(:codes).where(codes: {id: code.id})`

Please note that if you don't need to use codes entities later you should use `joins` instead of `includes` since it won't instantiate ActiveRecord objects which adds overhead

Answer (score 0):

```
@records = @records.includes(:codes).where(codes: {id: code.id})
```

Where `code` is a Code object which is the one you want to be filtered.